# Django Assigning BoundField Value

Tags: python, django

I know that we could access a form BoundField value by using this way

```
form = ItemFormAdmin
value = form['somekey'].value()
```

But how can I assigning a value to a boundfield? I tried this way

```
form = ItemFormAdmin
form['somekey'] = value
```

But it says `'ItemForm' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assinging value to `BoundField` doesn't make sense. The form is already submitted and user won't see you value.

If you want to alter field's value before it appear in `cleaned_data`, override `somekey_clean` or `clean` method.

If you want to set initial value (something that in input before the form is submitted) use this (in form's `__init__`)

```
form.fields['somekey'].initial = value
```

Edit 1

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
# ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()

        # get "some info from the form"
        part1 = cleaned_data.get('part1_field', '')
        part2 = cleaned_data.get('part2_field', '')

        # "manipulate it to fill another filed"
        cleaned_data['another_field'] = part1 + part2

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I want to set the value after the submission but before save() method. Could you give example how to do this? Currently I am doing it in `save_model()` method. The idea is, I need to get some info from the form and manipulate it to fill another filed of the same form before submission.